# What is the resolution of xnu's clock_get_time for CALENDAR_CLOCK?

Tags: c, macos, xnu

What is the resolution of the xnu kernel function clock_get_time for CALENDAR_CLOCK?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, OS X uses the [TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) on x86. This makes the precise granularity processor-specific, but almost certainly "good enough" for pretty much all purposes. For a definitive answer, check the source code though…